# magic 360 product view doesn't take more then 30 pics? How to pass img src as a parameter so that it takes more then 60 images to 360 rotate?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML and JavaScript mixed code snippet which is using a plugin called magicbox 360 toolkit, but it won't take more than 30 images even when there are many pics present in the folder. I tried their documentation; nothing seems to work.

```
<div class="app-figure" id="zoom-fig">
    <!--    <a id="spin-1" class="Magic360" data-options="rows:55; columns:55"-->
    <!--        href="images\armani-bag\armani-bag-small-01-01.jpg">-->
    <!--    <img src="images\armani-bag\armani-bag-small-01-01.jpg"></a>-->

    <!-- <a id="spin-1" class="Magic360" data-options="rows:55; columns:55 "> <img src="images\armani-bag\p-01.jpg"></a> -->
    <a class="Magic360" data-options="filename:p-01-{row}-{col}.jpg; rows:4; columns:12;"><img src="images\armani-bag\p-01.jpg""/></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the first spin image is `p-01.jpg`. This does not match the filename descriptor, which is `p-01-{row}-{col}.jpg`.

Without knowing the file names of your images, I guess the answer is:

1. Either the descriptor should be `p-{col}.jpg`.
2. Or the first image should be something like `p-01-01-01.jpg`.

What are the file names of your images?